# How to deal with users updating the same MongoDB document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

I have a Mean Stack app with multiple users who will use the app at the same time. I am not worried about what happens if they update a document at exactly the same time because MongoDB deals with that. My issue is the case where

1. User 1 loads document
2. User 2 loads document
3. User 1 updates document
4. User 2 updates document 10 seconds later

In this case user 2 will never have seen the updated version of the document. Is the best way to deal with this by sending the original version of the document in the request to see whether it has changed and return an error if it has?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to MongoDB and just starting researching it. This is a question I also have and I think I have a solution though I must still test with some code.

Create a versioning field in your document. Then:

On a standalone server use [db.collection.findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) and query by _id and current document version field. Set upsert to false. Increment the version field in the about-to-be-updated document.

> When modifying a single document, both findAndModify and the update()
>   method atomically update the document.

On replica sets use [Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/)

Mongoose 5.2.0 [includes this feature](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) as well.

> Transactions are new in MongoDB 4.0 and Mongoose 5.2.0. Transactions
>   let you execute multiple operations in isolation and potentially undo
>   all the operations if one of them fails.